# How to limit DocuSign request to either wet signing or signature drawing

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm looking for a way to limit certain signing requests to either wet signing *or* signing by drawing the signature, but not through the use of the adopted signatures.

I've already managed to restrict the signing to only wet signatures by using `signer.RequireSignOnPaper = "true"`, however, I need to be able to account for tablet devices, so it would be best to allow the user to draw their signature as well.

I’ve asked DocuSign support and they seem to suggest that it’s possible under the *Business Pro Plan* by using the *Adopt signature configuration*, but I haven’t been given any more detail than that.
Preferably this restriction on signing would be possible to apply to specific envelopes through the API, but I’d still be interested in any account wide option.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the signature to be drawn and not adopted from one of the pre-set styles, then yes you can set this on the account level (impacting all envelopes from that account) via the adopt signature configuration. Another way to force a signature to be drawn is to enable 'sign in each location (SIEL)', which requires the recipient to draw the signature/initials on each and every tab on the document.